# Git merge branch from detached

Tags: git, github, merge, git-detached-head

I have [sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohHQi.png) where `git merge` gives unexpected for me result.

Here `master` branch has commit #3 with unwanted changes. I checkouts to stable commit #2 and creates new branch with additional usage. Can I merge `new_branch` into `master` with all three lines? Thanks for help!

[image: Commit tree]

[Link to repository](https://github.com/DmitryKurtaev/git_demo)

Comment: So you want `master` to point to `new_branch`?

Comment: Yes you can do the merge, but is this something you really want to do?  Your question is not clear enough to me to understand the business logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can merge `new_branch` into `master` then revert #3.

Or, you can reset `master` to `new_branch`

`git checkout master
git reset --hard new_branch`

Answer (score 0):

you should make commit `#3` and `#4` into new_branch, try rebase command

```
git checkout new_branch
git rebase master
git checkout master
git merge new_branch
```

If there is a conflict, you should resolve it.

Or just make your changes into the master branch